# Sending Raw data to embedded System with websocket in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, websocket

I try to connect my PC with `node.js` and `Websocket` to a embedded system that communicates via JSON strings. Previously i was convinced that an `xhr request` would be sufficent to do this, but i have learned using wireshark, that there is to much overhead using `xhr`, and i am not able to include an `end of line or carriage return` to the JSON string, that is required by the embedded system as I get a `invalid or unexpected` token error everytime i add the `\r` in the string.

```
('{"id":7, "Client_ID":"webinterface", "method":"OutBit", "param": 
[10,1], "jsonrpc":"2.0", "protocol":"2X"}\r');
```

I have searched for examples on stackoverflow, and it seems that websocket can be used to send and receive raw data, but im not sure if this code is set up correctly and if its meant to be used by a `client` PC.

The embedded system only needs a JSON String with an end of line character. It sends back a JSON String with updated values after connecting. I cannot change the behaviour of the embedded system communication as its custom made hardware.

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://1.100.0.280:9398");
ws.send('{"id":7, "Client_ID":"webinterface", "method":"OutBit", "param": 
[10,1], "jsonrpc":"2.0", "protocol":"2X"\r}');
```

with the code above I receive a:

> WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING) error.

Is it even possible to use Websocket with a non websocket / embedded System Server?

Comment: You have to wait until ws is open until sending message. Try something like `ws.on('open', () => { /* now you are ready */ });`

Comment: @ prashant i receive this error if i run the code: 'node websocket2.js events.js:183       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event'